# Animation is not smooth

Tags: android, android-animation

I use animation in my app. Animation that I use is `slide_left` and `slide_right`. I faced the following problem: animation shown while sliding left is smooth and fine but when I slide right, the animation is not as smooth as shown while sliding left. So why this problem occurs? Here is my code please check if there are any errors.

**Code for slide_left.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**Code for slide_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromXDelta="-150%p" android:toXDelta="0"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**Code for .java file**

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) 
{
    switch (e.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            //store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
            m_downXValue = e.getX();
            break;
        }   
        
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            //Get the X value when the user released his/her finger
            float currentX = e.getX();
            
            // going forwards: pushing stuff to the left
            if (m_downXValue > currentX && currentX < 0)
            {                   
                ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipview);
                vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left));                
            }
            
            // going backwards: pushing stuff to the right
            if (m_downXValue < currentX && currentX > 100)
            {                   
                ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipview);                                     
                vf.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right));                                
            }                                       
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this Code for Left Side...

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="@string/duration"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="Duration" />
</set>
```

And Put this Code for Right Side...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="@string/duration"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="Duration" />
</set>
```

in that just Add your Duration...

It's Work...

Comment: put these inside <set></set> or outside

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3652/discussion-between-anshuman-and-miteshtechme)